# Password field without text security

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, webkit, extjs

I am doing a PhoneGap/Sencha touch 2.0 application, using xTemplates to render HTML. Performance is an issue and somehow it happens that typing in a `<input type='password'>` tag goes a lot faster than typing in a `<input type='text'>` tag (meaning the delay between the moment when the character  is tapped on the virtual keyboard and the moment when it actually appears in the input box is *a lot* shorter with `type=password`)

I have no idea why this is, and i feel like I don't really have time to solve the performance issue from it's root cause (project coming to an end very soon)

The easiest workaround I see is just disabling the text-security and have my input/text boxes just be of password type.

I thought this was supposed to do the trick :

```
-webkit-text-security: none;
```

But I just can't get it to work,

Am I missing something here? (I've tried to add it `inline` and as `!important`, but without any luck)

Comment: No, `-webkit-text-security` will add text masking to text inputs, but [doesn't apply to password inputs](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/password-input-bullet-alternatives/). Beyond that, you realize this is a bad idea security-wise, yes? (think XSS)

Comment: Actually, i dont see exactly how this would make the app more vulnerable to XSS then it already is, i thought webkit-text-security was only on a display level, i dont think the password text itself is encoded any differently, or is it?

Comment: Yeah on second thought there's probably not an increased XSS risk, but browsers do treat password fields differently (auto-fill, copy, what happens on page refresh, etc.) that could effect security.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the password field is an extended Ext.field.Text, which is probably what you are using on your other poor performing field.

This is from sencha-touch-all-debug.js:

```
Ext.define('Ext.field.Password', {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Text',
    xtype: 'passwordfield',
    alternateClassName: 'Ext.form.Password',

    config: {
        /**
         * @cfg
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        autoCapitalize: false,

        /**
         * @cfg
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        component: {
            type: 'password'
        }
    }
});
```

I'm guessing the that the speed benefit you are seeing is from reducing the character look-up to a single character?  That is a total guess though.

With Sencha Touch you are highly dependent on the WebView control and how well it works on a particular platform.  If this is on Android 3.0 platform, just tell your customer to suck it up or don't to support that platform.  Even the Sencha Touch example code has jittery scrolling and performance issues on a platform or 2.  For me, Android 3.0 was the worst.  I hear 4.0 fixed the issues.

Poor performance in webview running in 3.0 and 3.1
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17458

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I am not using sencha's password field, i am using a typical HTML <input> tag rendered within an xTemplate object. (there are other reasons why this is witch would be long to get into). I dont think the single char lookup makes the difference as the character just typed is displayed as such and is only transformed in the circle when the next character is entered. I just dont get why an INPUT tag with type=text is slower then when with type=password...makes NO sense to me...